# Best Practice to write Connection string for heavy traffic ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, traffic

What is the best way to define connection string for a web application that has minimum 500 live users on the internet in terms of connection pooling.
And load factors to consider?

Suppose I have connection string as follows:

```
initial catalog=Northwind; Min Pool Size=20;Max Pool Size=500; data source=localhost; Connection Timeout=30; Integrated security=sspi"
```

as Max Pool Size is 500 and as live users exceed 500 say 520 will the remaining 20 users experience slower page load??

Or what if I have connection string as follows which doesn't talks anything about pooling or Connection time out? How the application behaves then?

```
initial catalog=Northwind; data source=localhost; Integrated security=sspi"
```

I'm using "Using statements" however to access the MYSQL database.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking here - a connection string is a connection string - it just defines how the application connects to a database. What issues are you having? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A connection is not used continually by a user - it will only be used for the database query then returned to the connection pool (that is, it is *highly* unlikely that the 500 users will be utilizing 500 connections at the same time).

If the connection pool *is* depleted then, yes, additional database users will have to wait for new connections and will probably get a slower experience (if not an error outright).

Comment: @hungrycoder - Stress testing the application - using some load generator tool.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to declare a connection for each User. All this is fortunately managed by your SQL Server. The connection Pool will be used to handle all the incoming queries.

Please check the MSDN 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.100).aspx

**Important point**

> Caution We strongly recommend that you always close the connection
>   when you are finished using it so that the connection will be returned
>   to the pool. You can do this using either the Close or Dispose methods
>   of the Connection object, or by opening all connections inside a using
>   statement in C#, or a Using statement in Visual Basic. Connections
>   that are not explicitly closed might not be added or returned to the
>   pool. For more information, see using Statement (C# Reference) or How
>   to: Dispose of a System Resource (Visual Basic) for Visual Basic.